# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException with Sun Java System Application Server 9.1 and Postfix Mail server

Tags: exception, glassfish, ejb, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

In my application, I have the following Message Driven Bean to connect to the Postfix SMTP server to send emails to user:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/OutgoingEmailQueue", activationConfig =  {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class OutgoingEmailBean implements MessageListener {
    //Resource
    @Resource(name = "mail/MailSession")
    private Session mailSession;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            ....
            //Create the email
            javax.mail.Message email = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            ....
            //Send the email
            Transport.send(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I deploy this application using NetBeans with GlassFish 2.1 on my laptop, it can connect to the SMTP server and send out emails perfectly. However, when I copy all the settings over to the online Sun Java System Application Server 9.1 and deploy my application, my application no longer can send out emails. Instead, I got the exception javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException at the line "Transport.send(email)". In the server log, I saw these lines:

```
[#|2011-08-01T15:18:02.077+0400|SEVERE|sun-appserver9.1|ejb.Mailing.OutgoingEmailBean|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 665;_RequestID=52699cfe-71a2-46be-83b0-f3af23d74c0c;|The log message is null.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
    at ejb.Mailing.OutgoingEmailBean.onMessage(OutgoingEmailBean.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:176)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:3986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1111)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at $Proxy93.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:258)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:76)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
|#]
```

I spent 2 days looking around to make sure all the local settings of GlassFish 2.1 are identical to the settings of the online appserver but I still cannot solve the problem. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me an advice on how to tackle this issue.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: Did you set all the properties like `mail.smtp.user`, `mail.smtp.host`, `mail.smtp.port`? - You have to set these when using the static Transport call. See the SMTP package summary for a list of properties: http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Comment: I didn't explicitly add those properties in my code but in the setting for the "mailSession" on the app server, I have already set 3 compulsory properties: "Mail host", "Default User" & "Default Return Address" and 3 additional properties: "mail-smtp-port", "mail-smtp-password" & "mail-smtp-auth". Please tell me if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in Postfix configuration, "mynetworks" property didn't include the IP address of my domain. After adding the IP address, my application can send out emails normally already.